# How to get the density of a screen?

Tags: android, screen

How to get density of a screen? I have tried with the following code. I got density as `1.0`. I changed my emulator TO `HVGA`, `QVGA` and `WVGA` still I am getting the same result.

```
int density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

How to get actual density of my emulator screen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check with this code,

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();    
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);    
int screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
```

Answer (score 12):

If you only have access to a context and not the actual Activity object, you will not be able to use getWindowManager().

I had to use this approach:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This.

http://www.androidwarriors.com/2016/01/how-to-find-different-devices-screen.html

```
public static int differentDensityAndScreenSize(Context context) {
  int value = 20;
  String str = "";
  if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
   switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    str = "small-ldpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    str = "small-mdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    str = "small-hdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    str = "small-xhdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    str = "small-xxhdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    str = "small-xxxhdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    str = "small-tvdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   default:
    str = "small-unknown";
    value = 20;
    break;
   }

  } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
   switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    str = "normal-ldpi";
    value = 82;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    str = "normal-mdpi";
    value = 82;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    str = "normal-hdpi";
    value = 82;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    str = "normal-xhdpi";
    value = 90;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    str = "normal-xxhdpi";
    value = 96;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    str = "normal-xxxhdpi";
    value = 96;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    str = "normal-tvdpi";
    value = 96;
    break;
   default:
    str = "normal-unknown";
    value = 82;
    break;
   }
  } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
   switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    str = "large-ldpi";
    value = 78;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    str = "large-mdpi";
    value = 78;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    str = "large-hdpi";
    value = 78;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    str = "large-xhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    str = "large-xxhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    str = "large-xxxhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    str = "large-tvdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   default:
    str = "large-unknown";
    value = 78;
    break;
   }

  } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
   switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    str = "xlarge-ldpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    str = "xlarge-mdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    str = "xlarge-hdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    str = "xlarge-xhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    str = "xlarge-xxhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    str = "xlarge-xxxhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    str = "xlarge-tvdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   default:
    str = "xlarge-unknown";
    value = 125;
    break;
   }
  }
// The Toast will show the Device falls in Which Categories.
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  return value;
 }
```

Comment: Nice answer (Y)

Answer (score 1):

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    float density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    if(density==1.0){    **//This is for mdpi**

        params.width = 70;
        params.height=70;
        dynamicSeekBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        //              Toast.makeText(this, "1.0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else if(density==1.5){   **//This is for hdpi**

        params.width =110;
        params.height=110;
        dynamicSeekBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        //              Toast.makeText(this, "1.5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(density==2.0){   **//This is for xhdpi**

        params.width = 177;
        params.height=175;
        dynamicSeekBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        //              Toast.makeText(this, "2.0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```